# Exist in list c#

Tags: c#, list, exists

I'm trying to know if my element [3] exist in my list :

```
List<String> Elements = Ligne.Split(',').ToList();
     if (Elements[2] != ""){
         if (Elements[3] != ""){//do something}
         else{//do another thing}
```

My "Ligne" can have 3 elements (0,1,2) or 4 (0,1,2,3) and i can't test if my Elements[3] exist or not because if it doesn't exist visual studio says -> "Index limit reach".

Comment: You need to put an if before to check if the count is 3 or 4.

Comment: Use `Count` property to know the length of your list and then test index `2`or `3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [.exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check if a list element exists or not. A `bool` value is returned (found being true, false being not found).

In your situation, it would look something like this (***Disclaimer: This code may not compile***):

```
List<String> Elements = Ligne.Split(',').ToList();
bool myValueExists = Elements.Exists(x => x[3] != null);

 if (myValueExists){
    /* Proceed with whatever you desire */
}
```

This method is clean and concise. No need to worry about how many elements are inside your list. It's also very easy for future developers to recognize and understand.

[Additional source](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-exists)

Answer (score 1):

You can check how many elements are in list;

```
List<String> Elements = Ligne.Split(',').ToList();
     if (Elements[2] != ""){
         if (Elements.Count > 3 && Elements[3] != ""){//do something}
         else{//do another thing}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
List<String> Elements = Ligne.Split(',').ToList();
     if (Elements[2] != ""){
         if (Elements[3] != ""){//do something}
         else{//do another thing}
```

You've assumed that there will be at least 4 elements. However. what if thats not the case? clearly a condition occurs when thats not true, easiest fix is

```
if (Elements.Count>2 && Elements[2] != "")
{
  if (Elements.Count>3 && Elements[3] != ""){//do something}
  else{//do another thing}
}
```

Comment: Count is not a function its a property

Comment: sorry, in some places of course its function.. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

One way to check might be to test the `Elements.Count` property to see if there are 4 elements. Since you are dealing with a string that may or may not have that many elements after the split, this might be the way to go.

```
List<String> Elements = Ligne.Split(',').ToList();
if (Elements[2] != ""){
  if (Elements.Count >= 4){//do something}
  else{//do another thing}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `Elements.Count` - this will tell you the number of elements in the list.

```
List<String> Elements = Ligne.Split(',').ToList();
if (Elements.Count >= 3 && Elements[2] != "") 
{
    if (Elements.Count >= 4 && Elements[3] != "")
    { /*do something*/ }
    else
    { /*do another thing*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newList = Elements.Select((val, idx) => new { Value = val, Index = idx});
```

Using Linq like this you can get a new list of custom object which contain your value associated with an index. Now you can easily check if item with specific index exists:

```
if (newList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Index == 3) != null)
{
    // do something
}
```